# v5.6.2 User cannot stay logged in - wordpress_test cookie placed but not auth cookies

Tags: login, cookies

Running WordPress v5.6.2 with a simple Members Only function checking is_user_logged_in() and running auth_redirect() - which has worked fine up to now.

Pushed upgrade to 5.6.2 and now any browser with prior experience of the domain name cannot stay logged in - taken to login page, successful authorisation and loading of the requested page, but on navigating to the next page (i.e away from dashboard to any admin page) the user is returned to the login screen.

Checking the cookies saved by the domain wordpress_test is present, but the normal wordpress_auth cookies are not.

Clearing private data on the affected browsers doesn't change anything - but browsers which have never visited the site before are *mostly* OK.

Browsers are mostly Chrome (OSX), but can replicate on Edge (Windows) too. Have followed sensible troubleshooting steps:

- Ensure browser can login to other WordPress sites (yes)
- Ensure browser private data cleared
- Ensure browser permits cookies and disable adblock tools.
- Ensure credentials are correct (login fails with wrong credentials)
- Ensure WordPress site URLs are set correctly with no errant characters

Would be extremely grateful for any previous experiences with this kind of issue - it is driving me slowly mad.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue, but right now there's not enough information to diagnose what the problem is and answer the question. This isn't a forum so you need a specific question that can be answered with facts, not an open investigation. I'm assuming you did not modify WordPress core files, and you have done the standard debugging techniques of disabling everything, testing, then turning it back on 1 by 1 to locate the cause?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I apologise for missing the key data: no core mods, have disabled all plugins and swapped back to a default theme (issue persists). Safari (OSX) can remain logged in, anything Chromium based which has touched the site in the past cannot persist a session. Incognito also fails but deleting everything (literal Chrome profile) works until you sign into a Google account, suggesting something is syncing that shouldn't be!